# Practical significance of number of singular values in SVD

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, svd, singular-matrix

I am working on a binary classification problem. SVD is used for dimensionality reduction and the vector with reduced dimension is used as the feature vector. DNN is used as the classifier.

There are two datasets which I am working on. On one of the datasets, I get good accuracies for dimension around 60 (i.e., I am using only around 60 singular values) and for the other dataset, I need to take around 200 singular values for the same performance.

What does this tell about the two datasets? Does that mean that dataset one has less variance than dataset two?

Answer (score 0):

Doing linear dimensionality reduction just means that you project your data to a linear subspace, so you replace your data with a new one. I.e. if your first dataset works best with a reduction to 60 dimensions, this might indicate that your dataset is actually only of dimension roughly 60, but it could also mean that the projection to the 60-dimensional subspace removes most of the "detrimental" noise while keeping a sufficient signal level. In general, you can have more variance in the lower-dimensional datasets than in higher-dimensional ones, and, of course, also the other way around.